# Can someone explain me this code? It gives the reverse of the number we enter

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    long long n,i;
    cout << "Please enter the number:- \n";
    cin >> n;
    while (n!=0) 
    {

        i=n%10;   // what is the use of % here? 
        cout << i;
        n=n/10;
    }
return (1);


}
```

I want to understand how this code works. Why does it do what it does? If we enter 5123 it will give out 3215. How ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: % is the modulo operator. Mod 10 gives you the last digit.

Comment: Will try debugging, thanks!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: Single step (looking at the variables) when debugging. Don't just press F5 (or whatever key runs your program in the debugger on your IDE).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Glad I found a lively forum!

Comment: Technical note: You have't found a forum. You've found a question and answer repository. You will find Stack Overflow has a very different goal and set of backing ideologies than a forum. I recommend [a trip through the site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see just how different.

Answer (score 2):

[The very basics of C family languages](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), operator % gives the remainder of its left hand side argument when divided by the right hand side one. So, `n % 10` is `n`'s last digit in decimal notation (for instance, 3 for 5123.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Long story short:

> operator `/` performs **floor division**: only integer part returned, without remainder,
>
> operator `%` returns **remainder** of division operation

#### If needed, below is line by line explanation.

```
long long n,i;
```

defines variables `n` and `i` of type `long long` (64-bit unsigned integer).

```
cout << "Please enter the number:- \n";
```

prints out a prompt message hinting what is the expected input.

```
cin >> n;
```

is a command waiting for standard input, that is saved in int variable `n`.
Please note that invalid value (non-numeric) will cause an error later.

```
while (n!=0)
```

starts a loop that would be terminated when/if `n` becomes equal to zero.

```
i=n%10;   // what is the use of % here?
```

This command returns a remainder of division of value of variable `n` by `10`.
The result of this operation is saved to variable `i`.
E.g.

```
5123 % 10 = 3
 512 % 10 = 2
  51 % 10 = 1
   5 % 10 = 5
```

Next,

```
cout << i;
```

prints the value of variable `i` to stdout and keeps the cursor on same line, next column. Doing so in a loop it would print out each new value of variable `i` in a single line, faking a reverse integer number.

And, finally,

```
n=n/10;
```

performs operation of "floor division" (division without remainder - returns integer part only) of value of variable `n` by `10`. Result is saved back to variable `n`:

```
5123 / 10 = 512
 512 / 10 = 51
  51 / 10 = 5
   5 / 10 = 0    // after this iteration the loop will terminate
```